# Where can I find the BlueSnap Apple Pay integration Documentation?

Tags: e-commerce, applepay, wallet, bluesnap

I want to start researching wallets and I'm currently checking on the Apple Pay.

A colleague told me BlueSnap have new Apple Pay integration - but I'm not sure where is information.

Anyone? Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BlueSnap recently released the Apple Pay integration and it went live on June 4th, 2017.

You can find the documentation page in our Developers hub, under this link:
https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/apple-pay

Good luck with your research!